# Is there a way to use inputbox and enter multiple lines?

Tags: bash, input, cocoadialog

I want to have a simple way to enter messages for employees to see upon logging in.  It doesn't have to be date specific, although that would be nice, but I can't find a way to use dialog to allow me to enter multiple lines of text before I cat to the file.

Little help?

```
#!/bin/sh
DIALOG=${DIALOG=dialog}
tempfile=`tempfile 2>/dev/null` || tempfile=/tmp/test$$
trap "rm -f $tempfile" 0 1 2 5 15

$DIALOG --title "Bulletin Board Entry" --clear \
        --inputbox "Enter Today's Very Important\n
employee information below:" 16 51 2> $tempfile

retval=$?

case $retval in
  0)
    echo "Input string is `cat $tempfile`";;
  1)
    echo "Cancel pressed.";;
  255)
    if test -s $tempfile ; then
  cat $tempfile
else
  echo "ESC pressed."
fi
;;
esac
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `--editbox emptyfile` instead of `--inputbox`. Unfortunately this won't allow you to pass `/dev/null` instead of `emptyfile`, so you'll actually have to create an empty (temporary) file. Or a file containing a message template.

Comment: I'm on redhat RHEL5 and I don't have editbox available.  Any workaround?

Comment: You could grab the latest sources from the [dialog homepage](http://invisible-island.net/dialog/dialog.html), compile them yourself and call them by explicit path for this invocation. Unless you want to install this latest version system-wide.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to `dialog`, you could simply fire up an editor with the temporary file. That way, every user might even be able to use his or her preferred `$EDITOR`, instead of the feature-limited `dialog`. Many applications do this kind of thing when they want user input. Version control systems in particular come to my mind here.

Answer (score 0):

> a simple way to enter messages for employees to see upon logging in

For the purpose of displaying a file, there's `--textbox file height width` instead of `--editbox filepath height width` as suggested. They're also `--tailbox file height width` and `--tailboxbg file height width`.

For the purpose of displaying a text (not in a file but from a variable or directly provided quoted), they're `--infobox text height width` or `--msgbox text height width` or `--yesno text height width`, but not `--inputbox text height width [init]`

I read in a comment that OP was under RHEL5 where [some of those widgets are missing](https://www.unix.com/man-page/redhat/1/dialog/) but they're alternatives as you can see.

> to allow me to enter multiple lines of text before I cat to the file.

Not clear for me: displayed texts or files aren't limited in number of lines. If the purpose is to let users fill the board, I'd go with use of `$EDITOR` as suggested, because it's more convenient and friendly for the users.